# Why does Grammarly say the verb 'were' is incorrect in 'There were a prince and a princess'?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

- There **was** a  prince and  a princess
- There **were** a prince and a princess

Why does Grammarly show 'were' as an error here? A prince + a princess  = 2 people

> Correct subject-verb agreement
>
> There <s>were</s> was a prince and...
>
> ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62Ybj.jpg))

Comment: Grammarly is wrong.

Comment: Does it complain if you type "Grammarly were wrong"?

Comment: Care is needed with clauses such as "There was / were two red cars and one green one", where "were" is preferred. By contrast, in "There was / were one green car and two red ones", singular "is"  is preferred by some speakers. This is sometimes referred to as the 'proximity rule'.

Comment: There is no doubt at all that when you have two singular nouns connected by and an "a" in front of the nouns, the verb is singular. Let's leave the plural to another question. Here's the plural: **A prince and princess were standing on the lawn**. Luke is right. Grammarly is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a quantity is explicitly stated, as in “Once upon a time there **were three** little pigs,” the verb *to be* always agrees in number with that quantity, even if it  isn’t a precise number, thus, “There **were a few** people already in line when we arrived.”

But if instead a bare list is stated and its first element is singular, then it is perfectly colloquial to use singular forms of *to be*. Thus one hears, “There **was a** dog **and a** cat curled up together asleep,” and “There **was a** man **and a** woman already in line when we arrived.”

Comment: Right, two singular things is "was" or "is". Absolutely, no doubt about this.

Comment: "There were men, women and children everywhere" does not state an explicit quantity, but "There **was** men women and children" is definitely wrong. So your description is missing some important info. Although it's true that it's usually fine to use singular *be* if the first NP in a list is singular, that's not why Grammarly says OP's sentence is wrong. It's because grammarly thinks that the complement of to *be* there is the singular NP "a prince". It's not smart enough to know what *and  a woman*  is in coordination with, and cannot tell what the real complement of the verb *be* is.

Comment: My answer edited per your comment, @Araucaria-Nothereanymore.

Answer (score 1):

When refering to more than one noun that come after the verb, the verb usually agrees in form with the **first of the nouns**. Not with the total number.

So, *there was a prince and two princesses*, but *there were two princesses and a prince*.

Comment: More than the question is asking, and incomplete. This is more complicated. Some constructions of mixed numerus do prefer plural agreement. However, in the simple case you are essentially correct.